# Clear SWT Browser cache

Tags: java, swt

Is there any way to get the cache of a SWT-Browser cleared? Preferably programmatically for MacOS and Windows, but of course any help is welcome.

*Some background information: I'm retrieving the browser's perfomance API values but they're quite 'misleading' if a page gets loaded again.
Of course I'd appreciate if you'd offer a better way getting these value.*

Thanks!

Comment: SWT just uses the OS browser, it doesn't have a cache of its own.

Comment: What a pity. I was hoping that there's something maybe undocumented despite of that.