# SWT Browser - which browser does it use?

Tags: java, swt

How can I tell which OS browser the SWT browser uses if there are multiple installed?

I am specifically asking about Windows and OSX.

This is related to [Clear SWT Browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212925/clear-swt-browser-cache) .

Comment: Note: On the newest versions of SWT you can set the browser up to always use Chromium, see the [SWT FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `browser.getBrowserType()` method. see: https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html#getBrowserType()

```java
// ... your code

final var browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);

browser.setUrl("https://www.google.com/");

/** 
 * Description: Returns the type of native browser being used by this instance. Examples: 
 * "ie", "mozilla", "voyager", "webkit"
 */
System.out.println(browser.getBrowserType());
```

---

### Or

Solution with JS: [Find browser type/version of SWT Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841400/find-browser-type-version-of-swt-browser)

```
// ... your code

final var browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);

browser.setUrl("https://www.google.com/");

System.out.println(browser.evaluate("var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem, M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\\/))\\/?\\s*(\\d+)/i) || []; if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) { tem = /\\brv[ :]+(\\d+)/g.exec(ua) || []; return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || ''); } if (M[1] === 'Chrome') { tem = ua.match(/\\b(OPR|Edge)\\/(\\d+)/); if (tem != null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera'); } M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?']; if ((tem = ua.match(/version\\/(\\d+)/i)) != null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]); return M.join(' ');"));
```